# Interval in which roots lie.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

For a quadratic equation, we have several conditions from which we can determine the interval in which the roots lie.

eg: If exactly one of the roots of a general quadratic equation lies in the interval $(k1,k2)$, it can be shown that $f(k1).f(k2) < 0 $.

My question is: Can these same conditions be applied for, say, a cubic equation? Or a biquadratic equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful about saying that $f(k_1) \cdot f(k_2) < 0$ whenever the root of a quadratic equation lies in $(k_1, k_2)$. For instance, the quadratic $y = (x-2)^2$ has a root on (1, 3), but $f(1)\cdot f(3) > 0$.

Therefore, if $f(k_1) < 0 < f(k_2)$ or $f(k_2) < 0 < f(k_1)$ there is guaranteed at least one root in the interval, using the Intermediate Value Theorem as mentioned in the other answer. *However*, you cannot assume that if the signs are the same there is not a root on that interval.

We can often use the IVT to find zeros of higher-order polynomials. For instance, you could make a table of values and then narrow down the intervals in which the roots lie depending on where the signs change. However, this does not help you find roots with a multiplicity of 2 (such as in the quadratic example I gave above).